# Customizing "Done" Bar Button on top of UIKeyboard using UI Appearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I've customized my navigationBar UIBarButtons using appearance in ios 5. However it is also editing the appearance of the DONE bar button on top of my keyboard (look at the image below to understand the button I'm talking about). How can I access that button's class, so I can customize that button separately?

[image]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://mhasantanim.wordpress.com/tutorial/iphone/customize-done-button/) could be proper answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appearance proxy's `appearanceWhenContainedIn` method, for example:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyViewController class], nil] 
    setBackgroundImage:clear 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal 
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

(this example sets the background image, but i'm sure you can apply that to your own customization).

For details: see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html